# Delete the [sheet] tag on Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, burninate-request, ambiguous-tags

[sheet](/questions/tagged/sheet) is ambiguous. It has no wiki entry, and it's unclear what was intended in its creation. It has been chosen by OPs to mean several different things:

- `UIModalPresentationFormSheet`: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4266581/uimodalpresentationformsheet-resizing-view)
- Cheat Sheet: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3085196/cheat-sheet-documentation-django-python)
- MS Excel: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12948392/is-there-a-way-to-find-a-range-within-a-range-in-excel), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15730146/how-to-change-font-color-of-particular-cell-apache-poi-3-9), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14737476/clone-rows-from-one-sheet-to-the-other-containing-a-value)
- Cocoa custom sheet: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6368397/how-to-change-the-point-to-slide-a-cocoa-custom-sheet), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9229405/custom-sheet-cant-click-buttons)
- Google Spreadsheet: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15338638/google-script-function-insertimageurl-x-y-dont-work)

There are 128 questions using the tag today, excluding that short list above, that I cleaned up.

I'm requesting that the tag be burninated.

It will probably come back, and be just as useful. Can [sheet](/questions/tagged/sheet) also be blacklisted, please?

Comment: I'm still seeing 128 questions on SO.

Comment: Click on the "newest" tab and all shall become clear.

Comment: I definitely don't want to see 'sheet' being used for Excel or other spreadsheet apps.

Comment: Sheet! This tag needs to be burned!